# How to query id with high score

Tags: php, sql

Could someone help me? I have a table "examination" with the following fields and passmarks.

```
Id | Idnumber | Mathematics | English | Geography | Biology | Swahili
1    va01       100           90        85          80        88
2    va02       90            90        90          90        95
3    va03       80            70        100         60        75
4    va04       100           100       100         98        90
```

How to query by using PHP and get result which will show first student, second, third, last and so on, according to high total marks scored?

> Example: va01(100+90+85+80+88=443), va02(90+90+90+90+95=455), va03(80+70+100+60+75=385), va04(100+100+100+98+90=488)

Here according to this va04 student will be a first one, va02 will be second, and so on.

Comment: `ORDER BY Mathematics+English...+Swahili`

Comment: Where do You store this data?

Comment: I stored in mysql database

Comment: It would be better to do this with three tables: `student`, `subject`, `student_subject`. The last of these will contain a foreign key to the other two, together with a result mark. That way you don't need to hold empty values for students that do not take a particular subject.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT examination.*, (examination.Mathematics + examination.English + examination.Geography + examination.Biology + examination.Swahili) AS total
FROM examination
WHERE 1
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: The WHERE is unnecessary